# Calculate required start date for work order excluding weekends to reach shipping date

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Suppose there is an order which we have to ship on 28/04/2023 12:00 PM and to finish that order we need 11d:03h:36m:10s time. Find datetime when we should start working on that order.

Conditions:

1. Planned start date should not fall in Friday 22:00 PM to Sunday 22:00 PM.
2. Also exclude Friday 22:00 PM to Sunday 22:00 PM if in Start and Ship date range.

In short we don't have to consider Friday 22:00 PM to Sunday 22:00 PM at any cost.

I tried with this code. It uses an initial guess for the start date by subtracting the required time of the work order from the shipping date and then tries to adjust it by taking weekends into account:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, time
import pytz

excluded_start_time = time(22, 0)
excluded_end_time = time(22, 0)
excluded_days = {4, 5, 6}

# straight subtraction of ship date and operation time.
# no friday and sunday logic applied
start_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 17, 8, 23, 50) 

end_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 12, 0, 0)

def count_weekends(start_date, end_date):
    while end_date.date() > start_date.date() or (start_date.weekday() in excluded_days and excluded_start_time <= start_date <=excluded_end_time):
        friday = datetime.datetime.combine(start_date + timedelta(days=(4-start_date.weekday())), datetime.time(hour=22))
        sunday = datetime.datetime.combine(start_date + timedelta(days=(6-start_date.weekday())), datetime.time(hour=22))
        if friday <= end_date <= sunday:
            start_date = start_date - timedelta(hours=48)
            
        end_date = end_date - timedelta(hours=24)
    return start_date

print(count_weekends(start_date, end_date))
```

But I got incorrect results, it returns 11/04/2023 08:23 AM, the correct answer should be 13/04/2023 8:23 AM.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. Are you trying to calculate the remaining time to delivery or the number of days it will take to deliver the order?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea I want to calculate time and Date when we should start working. to ship order on mentioned ship date. We have to subtract Ship date time and operation time, excluding `friday 22:00 pm to Sunday 22:00 pm`

Comment: You mean given that a user order a product and it takes 4 days for example to ship that product. Calculate the shipping start day excluding Friday 10PM to Sunday 10PM right?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea No!, you're thinking in reverse. We have Ship date and we have Operation Time to Create/Produce That Product. so based on that ship date and Operation time we have to find when we should start working on that product . so we can ship it on pre decided Ship date.

Comment: Can you please update your question by including all these details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

# Constants for weekdays
MONDAY = 0
TUESDAY = 1
WEDNESDAY = 2
THURSDAY = 3
FRIDAY = 4
SATURDAY = 5
SUNDAY = 6

NON_WORKING_START_TIME = time(22, 0)
NON_WORKING_END_TIME = time(22, 0)


def is_within_non_working_period(dt: datetime) -> bool:
    """Checks if the date is within the non-working period."""
    return any([dt.weekday() == FRIDAY and dt.time() >= NON_WORKING_START_TIME,
                dt.weekday() == SATURDAY,
                dt.weekday() == SUNDAY and dt.time() < NON_WORKING_END_TIME])


def shift_to_working_date(dt: datetime) -> datetime:
    """Shifts the date to the nearest working date."""
    if is_within_non_working_period(dt):
        days_to_shift = dt.weekday() - FRIDAY
        return datetime.combine(dt, NON_WORKING_START_TIME) - timedelta(days=days_to_shift, seconds=1)
    return dt


def calculate_start_date(ship_date: datetime, required_time: timedelta) -> datetime:
    """Calculates the start date for the order."""
    ship_date = shift_to_working_date(ship_date)
    start_date = ship_date - required_time

    working_time = count_working_time(start_date, ship_date)
    while working_time < required_time:
        # Add more time to the start date to meet the required time
        start_date -= required_time - working_time

        # Shift the start date to the nearest allowed date
        start_date = shift_to_working_date(start_date)

        # Recalculate the working time for the next iteration
        working_time = count_working_time(start_date, ship_date)

    return start_date


def next_non_working_date(dt: datetime) -> datetime:
    """Returns the next non-working date.

    >>> next_non_working_date(datetime(2021, 4, 30, 23, 0))  # Sunday 23:00
    datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 5, 22, 0)  # next Friday 22:00
    """
    if dt.weekday() == SUNDAY and dt.time() >= NON_WORKING_END_TIME:
        return datetime.combine(dt, NON_WORKING_START_TIME) + timedelta(days=5)
    elif dt.weekday() < FRIDAY or dt.weekday() == FRIDAY and dt.time() < NON_WORKING_START_TIME:
        days_to_shift = FRIDAY - dt.weekday()
        return datetime.combine(dt, NON_WORKING_START_TIME) + timedelta(days=days_to_shift)

    # The date is within the non-working period
    return dt


def next_working_date(dt: datetime) -> datetime:
    """Returns the next working date.

    >>> next_working_date(datetime(2023, 4, 30, 21, 0))  # Sunday 21:00
    datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 30, 22, 0)  # Sunday 22:00
    """
    if is_within_non_working_period(dt):
        days_to_shift = SUNDAY - dt.weekday()
        return datetime.combine(dt, NON_WORKING_END_TIME) + timedelta(days=days_to_shift)

    # The date is within the working period
    return dt


def split_working_ranges(start_date: datetime, end_date: datetime) -> list[tuple[datetime, datetime]]:
    """Splits the date range into working ranges."""
    assert start_date <= end_date

    working_ranges = []

    current_end_date = start_date

    while current_end_date < end_date:
        current_start_date = next_working_date(current_end_date)
        current_end_date = next_non_working_date(current_start_date)
        current_end_date = min(current_end_date, end_date)
        if current_start_date < current_end_date:
            working_ranges.append((current_start_date, current_end_date))

    return working_ranges


def count_working_time(start_date: datetime, end_date: datetime) -> timedelta:
    working_ranges = split_working_ranges(start_date, end_date)
    return sum([end - start for start, end in working_ranges], timedelta())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ship date and required time
    ship_date_str = "28/04/2023 12:00 PM"
    required_time_str = "11:03:36:10"

    # Convert required time string to timedelta
    days, hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, required_time_str.split(':'))
    required_time = timedelta(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

    # Convert ship date string to datetime
    ship_date = datetime.strptime(ship_date_str, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")

    # Calculate the start date
    start_date = calculate_start_date(ship_date, required_time)

    total_time = ship_date - start_date
    working_time = count_working_time(start_date, ship_date)
    non_working_time = total_time - working_time

    print("Start working on the order at:", start_date)
    print("Total time:", total_time)
    print("Working time:", working_time)
    print("Non-working time:", non_working_time)
```

Result:

```
Start working on the order at: 2023-04-13 08:23:50
Total time: 15 days, 3:36:10
Working time: 11 days, 3:36:10
Non-working time: 4 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for The Response but answer should be `13/04/2023 8:23 AM.`

Comment: Are you sure? I checked it manually and see that there are many more than 11 days between 13 and 28 of April.

Comment: yes there are 2 weekends in between these dates so we have to subtract  96 hours. I did it on pen paper 3-4 times :')  i just want to make it work dynamically for any kinds of inputs

Comment: Oh, I got it! Non-working hours shout be excluded from required_time as well. I'll fix it.

Comment: Fixed considering only working hours in required_time.

Comment: Thanks! it's working as i expected :)

Comment: Hi was using your solution and its working as it should be. but im having issue in this perticular case when inputs are `ship_date_str = "08/05/2023 12:00 PM"` and  `required_time_str = "00:61:00:00"`. i tried to do debug and found it goes in infite loop in `while condition` in this function `split_working_ranges`. cannot figure out why. :')

Comment: There was a bug in `next_non_working_date`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, time
import pytz

excluded_time = time(22, 0)
excluded_days = [4, 5, 6]
# friday = 4
# saturday = 5
# sunday = 6

start_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 17, 8, 23, 50) 
ship_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 12, 0, 0)

def count_date(start_date,ship_date):
    weekly_hours = 120 # max working hour in week (friday 22:00 to sunday 22:00 exclude day)
    total_working_hours = (ship_date - start_date).total_seconds() / 3600
    if total_working_hours > 120: # working hours more then one week hour   
        divided_hour = round(total_working_hours/120,0) # check total week in working hours
        minus_hours = divided_hour * 48
        final_start_date = start_date - timedelta(hours=minus_hours)
    elif start_date.weekday() in excluded_days:
        if start_date.weekday() == 4:
            # if start date in friday
            friday_date = (start_date).replace(hour=22,minute=00)
            sunday_date = (start_date + timedelta(days=2)).replace(hour=22,minute=00)
            diff = sunday_date - start_date
            final_start_date = friday_date - diff
        elif start_date.weekday() == 5:
            #if start date in saturday
            friday_date = (start_date - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=22,minute=00)
            sunday_date = (start_date + timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=22,minute=00)
            diff = sunday_date - start_date
            final_start_date = friday_date - diff
        elif start_date.weekday() == 6:
            #if start date in sunday
            friday_date = (start_date - timedelta(days=2)).replace(hour=22,minute=00)
            sunday_date = start_date.replace(hour=22,minute=00)
            diff = sunday_date - start_date
            final_start_date = friday_date - diff
    else:
        final_start_date = start_date
    return final_start_date
    
output_date = count_date(start_date,ship_date)
print("output_date--------",output_date)
```

output:

```
output_date-------- 2023-04-13 08:23:50
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).